# Componente em ReactJs re-renderizando componentes filhos sem necessidade, como contornar isso?

Tags: react, react-hooks, react-dom

Quando um componente **Pai** atualiza consequentemente seu(s) Filho(s) também e(são) atualizado(s), sem que no minimo mude qualquer valor de suas `props` e `states`, ***por exemplo***:

```js
function Filho({item}) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('atualiza');
  });
  return (
    <div>{item.id} - {item.name}</div>
  );
}
function Pai() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { id:'1', name:'example 1'},
    { id:'2', name:'example 2'}
  ]);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" 
          onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
          value={value}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        {
          items.map((item, i) =>
            <Filho key={i} item={item}/>
          )
        }
      </div>
    </div>
 );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Pai/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Aguarde ...</div>
```

todas as vezes que é digitado o componente `<Filho />` também renderiza todos os itens novamente, propondo um retrabalho desnecessário tem como resolver essa re-renderização?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem sim, com o `React.memo` (ou em classes com [PureComponent](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) que compara o `state` e `props` superficialmente, tomando os devidos cuidados com objetos complexos, ou seja, esse recurso são para componentes com objetos simples) da seguinte forma:

```js
let Filho = React.memo(({item}) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('atualiza');
  });
  return (
    <div>{item.id} - {item.name}</div>
  );
});
function Pai() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { id:'1', name:'example 1'},
    { id:'2', name:'example 2'}
  ]);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" 
          onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
          value={value}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        {
          items.map((item, i) =>
            <Filho key={i} item={item}/>
          )
        }
      </div>
    </div>
 );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Pai/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Aguarde ...</div>
```

nesse caso, ao digitar no `<input/>` o componente não é re-renderizado (como não houve mudanças) e isso tem um ganho em desempenho, mas, como foi dito tem suas restrições.